# Testing Mono.sequenceEqual

Tags: project-reactor

I'm trying to figure out how to verify `sequenceEqual` method in `Mono`.
My code is as follow:

```
Mono<Boolean> mono = Mono.sequenceEqual(Mono.just(1), Mono.just(1));
StepVerifier.create(mono)
    .expectNext(true)
    .expectComplete()
    .verify();
```

And here is the stacktrace I got

```
- java.lang.Throwable: Multiple exceptions
- java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "defaultOnSubscribe" failed (expected: onSubscribe(); actual: onNext(true))
- java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext(true)" failed (expected: onNext(true); actual: onComplete())
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.validate(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1337)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:827)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:533)
at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:508)
```

Comment: looks like you found a bug! the `sequenceEquals` operator doesn't propagate the subscription signal upstream. opened issue [#328](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/328)

Answer (score 0):

This operator isn't well-behaved with regard to subscription signal propagation, and since the `StepVerifier` expects a well-behaved `Publisher` all the way, you get an error.

To work around this [bug](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/328), you could regularly subscribe to `sequenceEqual` and have a custom subscriber capture the events in `AtomicReference` or similar then assert those...

Comment: It seems after I check GitHub history, `AssertSubscriber` is removed from 3.0.3 and 3.0.4. So I can't take your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Ah right it is not in the public API, but in the test root of reactor-core :(

Comment: So it seems I have to wait for the fix you're working on. I put some comment on one of the test